# how to solve slow running TSQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with a slow running query.
I have analysed the query with the sql server profiler but I can't seem to find a good solution.
I did find why it is running slow. If ask the full dataset it returns me 150 rows in 10s, if I added the sums and calculations it returns me 18 rows but it takes 8min.

In the sql server profiler I found out that the full dataset does about 1 000 000 reads and the sum query about 82 000 000. But I don't know how or why he is getting some many records. Because the full dataset is the sub select from the sum query.

the below query is an example not the real query(real query also has union all's in the sub query but the sum query is basically the same)

```
SELECT Sum(x) * 0.1,
       Sum(y),
       a
FROM   (SELECT x,
               y
        FROM   tx
        INNER JOIN ty ON tx.a = ty.a 
        WHERE  x = 1 --this returns 150 rows in 10s 
       ) sub 
GROUP  BY a -- sum returns 18row 8min
```

Can somebody help me with some more test I have to do or a solution a could test?
[image: First Piece execute plan]
[image: Second Piece]
[image: Third Piece]

Comment: Show your query plan.

Comment: You should include the `table structure` that is used by those queries as well as `index definitions` and then execute both those queries in `SQL Server Management Studio` and `include Execution plan taken` take screenshots of that and include it into your question

Comment: Are you sure that your query is working - there no column a in subquery. And why you use subquery?

Comment: Your execution plan looks considerably more complex than the stated query!

Comment: I would suggest asking this question over on dba.stackexchange as they have the skills to guide you on this. Also the reason for the degradation is definitely related to your sub query (so do not exclude it from your question)

Comment: Thanks I posted the question dba

Comment: what exactly is `a` referencing in the outer query as your subquery doesn't output `a`

Comment: I'd recommend you try to get rid of the `Table Scan`s and `Index Scan`s you can see in that execution plan, the most expensive operation seems to be at the top right (thick arrows). A Scan happens if your search criteria are not specific enough so the engine needs to parse through all rows - that's what makes it expensive. Do you have indexes on `tx.x`, `tx.a`, `ty.a`? (if yes plz include the code for those) that's where I would start to look and try to create new indexes that help speeding up those queries (or rewrite the queries to satisfy your already existing indexes)

Comment: You post an example that is not the real query. The example is not even valid syntax.  Then you post the query plan of real query.  From that how do you expect help with performance problems with the real query?

Comment: @Blam the real query is 630 lines.. If somebody would like to debug fine.But don't think anyone will do that. I'm looking for test that I can do so that I can debug..

Comment: How can you test a query with invalid syntax?  No way you know that query has the same performance problems of the real query as that query does not even run.

Comment: Thanks @DrCopyPaste! I looked at the scans and there was a bad link and a bad where clause. Now the sum query runs under 10s

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking down the query in to 2 steps using a temporary table to remove the sub query:

```
-- populate temp table
SELECT x, y, a
INTO #TEMP
FROM   tx INNER JOIN ty ON tx.a = ty.a 
WHERE  x = 1

-- query the temp table
SELECT Sum(x) * 0.1,
       Sum(y),
       a
FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY a
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing the aggregations twice.  In your example, this looks a bit non-sensical, but the structure is:

```
SELECT sum(x), sum(y)
       Sum(y),
       a
FROM   (SELECT a, sum(x) * 0.1 as x, sum(y) as y
        FROM tx INNER JOIN
             ty
             ON tx.a = ty.a 
        WHERE  x = 1 --this returns 150 rows in 10s 
        GROUP BY a
       ) sub 
GROUP  BY a ;
```

SQL should do a better job aggregating on the individual tables, combining the results and re-aggregating than it would do on aggregating on a `union` of the individual tables.  Also, if you are using `union` instead of `union all`, that will affect performance.